# PyCharm - Autocomplete Quotes - Go to Next Line from within Quotes

Tags: autocomplete, pycharm

I'm new to PyCharm.

I like that it autocompletes single and double quotes, but how do I "get out" from within the quotes and proceed to the next line without having to cursor or mouse over?

**Example:**

I start typing,

```
string = 'Hello World'
```

After I'm done with the letter *d*, my cursor is stuck there.

So is there a fancy way of hitting ENTER so that I can go to the next line without bringing the trailing quote with me?

I understand that I can just close the ' quote myself, but doesn't that defeat half of the purpose?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Easy. Once you finish writing the string, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd>. Viola, you're on the next line.

Comment: Thanks!  Can't believe I didn't find/try that.

Comment: @Berto If this worked for you, then please accept the answer.

Answer (score 5):

<kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd> works as well, I found.

Comment: shift+enter really works, it is better than ctrl + shift + enter